# ms sql server 2012 - ranking vendors based on transaction success rates by text area

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking, rank

I have a table of transactions that looks similar to:

```
EXP_ID  PICKUP_DATE     PICKUP_WARD_TEXT    STATUS  PRICE
  1         21/11/2013       W1                    1    20
```

There are lots of these transactions. Not all of these complete.

Status 1 is completed, status 2 is not completed. The difference between these is referred to as conversion.

Many vendors may take on transactions in any specific ward.

I am seeking to rank the effectiveness of a vendor in completing transactions, and replace poorly converting vendors.

I want to know the minimum conversion % and the maximum. Id also like to predict how much money (price) we would have made if all jobs were completed by the vendor with MAX conversion. - In this way I can size the potential 'loss' by selling to worse converting vendors.

My output looks similar to

```
PICKUP_WARD_TEXT    NUMBER OF VENDORS   BEST CONVERSION WORST CONVERSION    POTENTIAL LOSS - edit: BEST_VENDOR WORST_VENDOR
    W1                         12                0.98        0.91             £84,657.00                  06           78
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Is vendor identified by `EXP_ID`? What is`PICKUP_WARD_TEXT`?

Comment: Have tried to use the same row_number() trickery in my last question here, but thoroughly lost and believe that the min and max conversion not enough alone to size the potential loss and Ive gone very wrong. Right now I'm trying to put the min and max conversion (which I can do using casting) into two #temp tables - and joining these to a cte on my first dataset that calculates the min and max conversion. Not sure if this is the right approach either.

Comment: Pickup ward text is a text string of the geographic location the transaction occurs.

Comment: You sentence beginning with "Ideally" is hard to interpret.

Comment: Apologies; have re-written.

Comment: So number of vendors is not a `COUNT()` but an ID for the vendor?  Without a sample query the output is hard to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select pickupwardtext,count(*),min(successrate),max(successrate) from (
Select sum(case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end)/ sum(1) as    
successrate,vendorid,pickupwardtext from yourtable
Group by vendorid,pickupwardtext)
```

The rest you can join this table and get corresponding data